# List files/directories according to their modification time

Tags: command-line, ls

How can I list files or directories according their last modification time either in ascendant or descendant way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list files/dirs according to modification date, newest first

```
ls -lt
```

To list files/dirs according to modification date, oldest first

```
ls -ltr
```

Reading man page

`man ls`

```
 -t     sort by modification time, newest first

 -r, --reverse
              reverse order while sorting
```

Comment: you are welcome friend, glad to help

Comment: I tried `ls -c` and `ls --sort=time` but they do not show the time. With yours I see even the date which thing I wanted the most